# Can you explain this code where the return value of printf is assigned to a variable?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int num=4;
    num=printf("2");
    printf("%d",num);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `21`. Can you please explain the code?

Comment: The [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=msvc-160) tells you what the return value from `printf()` is. The program is outputting  `2` and then `1` which is seen as `21`.

Comment: This is one reason it's a good habit to end every `printf` format with a `\n`: `printf("2\n");`, `printf("%d\n", num);`.  Much less opportunity for confusion.

Comment: As a tip: Next time you ask the question, please also provide the output *you* were expecting. That can help other people understand your thought process, and will generally result in a better answer for you personally.

Answer (score 2):

The first `printf` writes a `2` to standard output, and returns the number of characters written, which in this case is `1`.  The second `printf` writes the value of `num` to standard output.  Since `num` is now `1`, it writes a `1`.

Comment: The documentation @Weather Vane linked to would be a good addition to this answer.